# Why does AFrame require Node?

Tags: aframe

I've read a bit about AFrame, and I am very familiar with Node.js.  But why does AFrame require Node to run?  I tried looking at the index.html in the Aframe boilerplate sample--and it runs just the same in the browser with or without Node running. Is Node really required to be running? What is Node rendering?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Node.js is not required to run A-Frame — it runs in a browser with no expectation that your server use Node vs PHP, or that you use a webserver at all. Are you seeing something that makes it seem like Node would be needed?

However, the [aframe-boilerplate](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe-boilerplate) starter kit does provide convenience features — used only during development — that rely on Node.js to automatically reload the page when your HTML changes, or deploy to GitHub Pages. These are not requirements for A-Frame itself, and can be ignored if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks Don.  Yes, the GitHub page includes using Node during the AFrame installation, but does not explain why Node is needed.  Thanks for your explanation.  Makes sense.

Comment: Yeah just local server. We could update that to be more clear.